# How to generate a signature from an audio record (Shazam like)

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to find a way to generate a signature from an audio record in order to compare it with other signatures to find a match (probably what shazam does among many other things). How can one parse sound amplitude and create markers (which is what I believe is the way to go)?

Answer (score 1):

For instance here is their iOS one, you would communicate in a similar manner https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-ios-sample

[Reference URL Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994221/can-you-suggest-web-api-for-music-identification-service-like-shazam)